# Caching with Pyramid

Tags: python, caching, pyramid, beaker

How can I cache my views and templates with Pyramid?

The docs talk about pyramid_beaker ( https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_beaker/en/latest/ ) but the page doesn't actually show how to use the cache.

The first result on google for "pyramid caching" is this - https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons-webframework/en/latest/caching.html but it's about Pylons, there are lots of interesting things - caching of views, controller actions, templates and fragments, is it possible to do that in Pyramid, and how?

Answer (score 0):

You should install [pyramid_beaker](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_beaker/en/latest/).

Then read the [beaker](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) documentation too.

Comment: I have installed it and read the docs. There is a missing piece of documenatation between pyramid_beaker and beaker, because the pyramid_beaker page doesn't tell me how to use it.

The beaker docs talk about cache managers and other things, how do I get them with pyramid_beaker?

Is there an example where all of it is used together?

Comment: Check this out too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292082/caching-with-beaker

Comment: if I do this: 
@cache.cache('index', expires=600)
    def index(self):

then I get an error about pickling the Response object.


Hm. It seems that pyramid doesn't do caching the way I want it to. Other frameworks can cache the the response, or parts of the rendered template.

Comment: Use memcached perhaps? :)

Comment: How exactly would you propose I do that? I was hoping that beaker or dogpile could be used to cache with any backend, a file, memcached etc.